# Use an explicit return of undefined as type guard and/or filter?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am trying to combine the array methods filter and map into one function called malter. I have come so far:

```ts
type mapFn<T, S> = (value: T, index: number, originalArray: Readonly<T[]>) => S;

interface Array<T> {
  malter<S = any>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S>): S[];
}

function notUndefined<T>(v: T | undefined): v is T {
  return typeof v !== "undefined"
}

Array.prototype.malter = function malter<T, S = any>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S>): S[] {
  return this.reduce(function(acc: S[], val: T, index: number, orgArr: T[]) {
    const el = mapFn(val, index, orgArr);
    if (notUndefined(el)) {
      acc.push(el);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
};
```

It basically works.
But when using it, it throws a TypeError in line 5-7.
Another test function that did implicitly return undefined did also throw that error.

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."
```

```ts
const test = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3];

function test1(): string[] {
   return test.malter<number, string>(num => 
      num > 3 
       ? num.toFixed(2) 
       : undefined
   );
}
```

A solution that would work type savely, is to provide 2 arguments for malter. A filter and a map function and call them seperately. That would ensure type savety, but also make it less simple.

Sure I could simply do that in line 5-7:

```ts
(num > 3 ? num.toFixed(2) : undefined) as string
```

It may be the best compromise?
What do you think? Is there a solution I didn't think of, or do you go with a compromise?

Comment: Line numbers don't really help for small snippets, just makes code hard to copy :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you have two `T` generic parameters in `interface Array<T> { malter<T = any, S = any>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S>): S[]; }`?  Why not just `interface Array<T> { malter<S>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S>): S[]; }`?

Comment: it's better now

Comment: And as to the question, looks like you should be doing something like `interface Array<T> {  malter<S>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S | undefined>): S[]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `undefined` as the value to be filtered. We can allow the inner function to return `undefined` and then filter it out using `Exclude`, much like the implementation does:

```
type mapFn<T, S> = (value: T, index: number, originalArray: Readonly<T[]>) => S;

interface Array<T> {
    malter<S>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S>): Exclude<S, undefined>[];
}

function notUndefined<T>(v: T | undefined): v is T {
    return typeof v !== "undefined"
}

Array.prototype.malter = function malter<T, S>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S>): Exclude<S, undefined>[] {
    return this.reduce(function (acc: S[], val: T, index: number, orgArr: T[]) {
        const el = mapFn(val, index, orgArr);
        if (notUndefined(el)) {
            acc.push(el);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
};

const test = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3];

function test1(): string[] {
    return test.malter(num =>
        num > 3
            ? num.toFixed(2)
            : undefined
    );
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the compiler is more able to understand `<T>(x: T | undefined) => T` or `<T>(x: T) => Exclude<T, undefined>`.  I'd kind of think the former only because it predates conditional types and has been supported longer, but who knows?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwDwBUB8AKAHgLkXUQB9FwATAU2BjCooEpD0BtAXUQG8AoRfxACcqUEIKS5EAfkStcnQhwDciAPSrEcANYBDAJ48Avj1CRYCRDAw4CRZogCiuCABsQ1DABpyYarXoUmBzcfALCouKIkjJyCrLsKuqIVIKCcILeEDpgAORQiLQA5mJUlvlwIFBGQA) of the difference.

Comment: @jcalz yeah you are right, works that way too .. do you want to post it ?

Answer (score 2):

[@TitianCernicova-Dragomir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56343076/2887218) is correct, but I'd also like to give a slightly different solution.  The main difference is that instead of using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to turn `S` (which possibly includes `undefined`) into to `Exclude<S, undefined>` (which doesn't), we take `S` as the return type (which doesn't include `undefined`) and use the input type as `S | undefined`.  They will act the same (or nearly so) from the caller's point of view (the compiler will do its own `Exclude`-like analysis on the input type), but the compiler will likely be able to reason about types inside the implementation of `malter` better in the latter case:

```
type mapFn<T, S> = (value: T, index: number, originalArray: Readonly<T[]>) => S;

interface Array<T> {
  // S will not include undefined when inferred from mapFn
  malter<S>(mapFn: mapFn<T, S | undefined>): S[];
}

// hey, look, this works the same way, with T|undefined => T
// instead of T => Exclude<T, undefined>
function notUndefined<T>(v: T | undefined): v is T {
  return typeof v !== "undefined";
}

Array.prototype.malter = function malter<T, S>(
  this: Array<T>, // inform the compiler that this is an array
  mapFn: mapFn<T, S | undefined> 
): S[] {
  return this.reduce(function(acc: S[], val: T, index: number, orgArr: T[]) {
    const el = mapFn(val, index, orgArr);
    if (notUndefined(el)) {
      acc.push(el);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}; // inference in implementation works


const test = [2, 3, 4, 5, 3];

// don't need any type parameters 
function test1(): string[] {
  return test.malter(num => (num > 3 ? num.toFixed(2) : undefined));
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAtghmAYgOwDwBUA0UDKA+KAXigAoA3OAGwFcIAuKLKAS2QBMIAPB5amAIwgAnbAHshzAOasqAQSFC4IBgCUIcNqOSUQGANoBdPAEoiBHAG4AUFdbBhAMzgBjaPMW70BAN5WoUAHoA3CgAd2ZKSihkUWAWZGcaDihqdggHVgg2MIALCGR4h2EhLKgHIVEYWAQUP2rKeyFUfBJ4JGQGNpQMbBwoAB8UtIzkLJMGHENrAF8bIKg8kGxKUVEAa2xgHOYAZzDxNb2t6B24GGhQpWxwrcZ+1I4R0sICdCt51h37DShRB0YzFAAKKcRLUDg9IaPTJsPBWBypZzAZhaaKxACqwxhGDw5AY6AGUPSMOMDDILD2BN8-hKwGoQgKoEgfyg5IAhIRiAAiB7E0ZsLkzGzuJQAOjAFWAsXAEFF8AawiIZURyNR8sakJadS2uwYIs8eGwH2QDnEVWOUGclTAEUVWzgcR1e12UDgBTgCiUdS6HWq7U1hN5T1hVlJuEMUGpUFp9MZ2x2opKbGorhICISquQJBczgmhmwFEo+OwrA43GifEEIl+Qkk7nxhlMUf8VuQXygECixB95CoJbSnDEtfcxms-n8zH+JBiwEx0P5JE7xibdXHrucznF1B2OUXlFHq6gszXMYZ6+cY6P2EbMwsgWCrCKJQS0FYLBgYEoEHOyGADpRBShAcOw2K27b2O2xB6AATNgADM2AACzYAArPBBjWO8wSaMgADkcSjKUbogFATLQGAHpnBAjQgemSIAaREBfAAjCQYZfBIyCSBGUanoyTHAHKVCNNOfCAqJVQEHBUAAPwVjAopSogzCcFkJDQaYDBBiSB6zEAA)

Comment: I like the technical insides of your answer. But as both presented solutions have the same outcome, from a developers standpoint it might be more expressive to go with the conditional type "Exclude". It may be not so obvious for this simple function, but in more complex scenarios, I sure think it does. Nethertheless, thanks for the detailed answer.